# SQL - inner join between large table and small table, with filters

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple SQL query that does an INNER JOIN between tables A and B, with filtering.  Table A is very large, whereas table B is fairly small.  I only want to return rows that match a certain filter, e.g., table_B.some_col IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd').  Of course, I have this filter as a WHERE clause.  However, it was recommended to me to duplicate the same filter, but for table A and to put it in the join.  For example,

```
SELECT
*
FROM table_A
INNER JOIN table_B
    ON table_A.pk = table_B.pk
    AND table_A.some_col IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
WHERE
table_B.some_col IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

It is claimed that doing so improves the query plan.  Unfortunately, due to security restrictions on my machine, I cannot inspect query plans.  Is this claim true?

Comment: hold on, your two queries are actually different queries, without the table_A.some_col IN... you would choose any selected from B with matching primary key in A - unless some_col in B is duplicate value in A

Answer (score 0):

Adding a filter at `And` or `Where` clause doesn't make any difference..

Here are some tests ..

***Query used..***
select * from 
orders o
join
 hr.employees h
 on h.empid=o.empid

***Filter at And Clause..***
and empid=4

**Execution plan**:
[image]

**Set statistics IO:**

```
Table 'orders'. Scan count 1, logical reads 20, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Employees'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

**Filter At Where Clause:**
where empid=4

**Execution plan:**
[image]

**Statistics IO:**

```
Table 'orders'. Scan count 1, logical reads 20, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Employees'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

In each case,SQLServer is smart enough to rearrange query (since it is inner join) and get only relevant rows